# 8GB USB drive reduced to 3MB, how can I recover the correct size?

Tags: usb, partitioning

After trying to copy a software from another system, my 8GB USB flash drive reduced to 3MB.

I checked the Disk Manager, it looks like this:

[image]

I couldn't see any unallocated space there..  Can I resize my drive?

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd as adminstrator and execute the following set of commands.
1.diskpart
2.list disk
3.select disk 0(Where disk 0 is your 4mb removable disk choose carefully)
4.clean

Then open disk management and claim your unallocated space by making a new drive.

Comment: The Disk Manager GUI should show the unallocated space...

Comment: I meant it should show it before the Clean.  Clean will not make missing unallocated space reappear - at least not in my experience. :)

Comment: May be but in my case it appears after cleaning,I keep on switching my usb from linux to windows and it has happened a couple of times that my 16 gb usb will be shown as having only a few mb of space,following the above mentioned steps usually brings back my space.